# Merging 2 subqueries having different number of rows. Getting double the data

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote an sql query which pulls data from a single table (`date,account,dr,cr`) depending upon a condition as follows:

```
select * from (select date,account,dr from sys_credit_debit where dr != 0) as t1,
(select date,account,cr from sys_credit_debit where cr != 0) as t2
```

I want to show the debit data on left side of the table and credit data on the right side. knowing the fact that rows can be different. But, I am getting the double data through the query.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What you are trying to do is writing two queries side by side. So you should do exactly that: Have two seperate queries. In your application, display them side by side. It is not the job of mysql to care (much) about how you display the data, mysql cares about managing (storing and getting) the data. Your application's job is to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM
(select date,account,dr from sys_credit_debit where dr != 0) as t1
INNER JOIN 
(select date,account,cr from sys_credit_debit where cr != 0) as t2
ON t1.account = t2.account AND t1.date = t2.date
```